# Typeof Error - Returning a NaN even though both is a number

Tags: javascript, date, type-conversion, nan

I tried to **find out the difference** between *diff* and *currentDate.getTimezoneOffset*.
I have checked that both of them are numbers,and yet it shows a NaN.

Here's my **js code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Grab the current date
    var currentDate = new Date();

    // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
    var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 0, 8, 4);

    // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
    var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;


    console.log(typeof parseInt(currentDate.getTimezoneOffset()))
    console.log(typeof diff)
    console.log(parseInt(currentDate.getTimezoneOffset()))
    console.log(diff)
    console.log(diff - parseInt(currentDate.getTimezoneOffset))

});
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how to resolve it?

Comment: You are not returning a number- use currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() to return an integer offset

Comment: @kennebec Sorry i did a small mistake,can u check again?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Your edit did not apply to the last part: `console.log(diff - parseInt(currentDate.getTimezoneOffset))`

Comment: @chris97ong Oh christ.. no wonder :| My bad.

Comment: Just a sidenote: `parseInt(currentDate.getTimezoneOffset)` is `NaN`, `typeof NaN === 'number'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong here:

```
   console.log(typeof parseInt(currentDate.getTimezoneOffset))
```

It should be

```
console.log(typeof parseInt(currentDate.getTimezoneOffset()))
                                                         ^^ missing brackets here
```

Comment: Yeh i forgot to add those,still the problem persists, check the updated qn.

Comment: You haven't corrected all the errors in your code.  With the correct syntax this works in my browser

Comment: Yeh i guess i should have slept a little more.
THanks for pointing it out. Typos...